Authorization header not displaying in the flask_smorest blueprints
I have a flask app that using the flask_smorest, pyJWT, flask_sqlalchemy and etc..
and I am creating the route /me to get current user details
but when I hit that url using postman it works fine with proper header. but not in the case of swagger UI. its not passing the Auth header while testing the endpoint using swagger UI.
I have declear a doc for add the auth in the blueprint.doc decorator like this -

def login_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        authorization = request.headers.get("Authorization", None)
        if not authorization:
            abort(403, message='no authorization token provided')

        auth_type, token = authorization.split(' ')
        if "Bearer" not in auth_type:
            abort(403, message="Token type should be bearer")
        try:
            decoded_token = jwt.decode(token)
            current_user = models.UserModel.get_by_email(email=decoded_token['identity'])
            return f(*args, **kwargs, current_user=current_user)

        except Exception as e:
            abort(401, message="Invalid or expired token")

    return wrapper

body = {
    'name': 'Authorization',
    'in': 'header',
    'description': 'Authorization Bearer <access_token>',
    'required': 'true',
    'default': "nothing",
}


@blp.route("/me")
class Identity(MethodView):

    @blp.doc(parameters=[body])
    @login_required
    def get(self, current_user):
        print(current_user)
        return {"data": current_user.to_json()}



the @blp.doc decorator works for every other header except the Authorization.

Maybe there is other in-build authorization method exists in the flask_smorest
please help me.
Even I pass like the args Schema way - its not passing through the swagger UI
@blp.arguments(AuthSchema, location='headers')
swagger-UI header

You will need to add to the app config:
API_SPEC_OPTIONS = {
    "components": {
        "securitySchemes": {
            "Bearer Auth": {
                "type": "apiKey",
                "in": "header",
                "name": "Authorization",
                "bearerFormat": "JWT",
                "description": "",
            }
        }
    },
}

And to method you should use the decorator with security param:
@api.doc(
   security=[{"Bearer Auth": []}],
)

It should produce the correct documentation. You can read more about this here https://github.com/marshmallow-code/flask-smorest/issues/36.
